# Websockets - Building a chatting system in Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, websocket

I need to build a conversations (chatting) feature on top of Laravel using Pusher.js.
To do this, I would need websockets for the real time chatting.

However, I am not sure at what would be the correct approach towards solving this in a professional manner.

**My current planned approach is:**

I plan on having multiple Pusher channels. Each `Conversation` (DB Model) would have a `channel_ID` column which would be the Pusher channel name, only accessible by Sender / Recipient. Front-end would be a chatting app with multiple conversations shown. Once user clicks on `conversation A`, it would `subscribe` to that conversation's `channel_ID` (Pusher Channel). Once they click on conversation B, it would `unsubscribe` from `channel A` and `subscribe` to `channel B`.

**My issues in the approach is following:**

In Laravel, each Broadcast Event (mine is called `message`) has a function `broadcastOn()`. However I do not know how would I make this work for say, 10 000 conversations with all having a different channel name? I don't know if this is optimal, it does not seem too good to me.

I've already Googled for a couple of days and looked up many websocket related guides. Many of them go into detail how to create a `public chat` with everyone receiving the event, but none of them really go into detail how to create an user-to-user secure chatting feature.

Comment: Sounds good, i made this way a few years ago maybe it can help you.
https://github.com/robbinbenard/laravel-chat-demo

Comment: I personally implement channels as one for each user. That allows me to keep the websocket connections to a minimum and also send a plethora of other notifications in real time.

Comment: @Shone Using another post it seems is the only way another user can be messaged.  I was just about to post an answer to your 2 of 3 left center right question when it got deleted. If you are able to repost your question in some form I can post my answer.  It is not a "pure" solution by your criteria, but it does I think go a significant distance to getting there.  Please ping me from any re-post if you do.

Comment: @petern0691 Well, I deleted that post since people got overly toxic for me asking regarding the best approach instead of posting a code problem.

Feel free to respond here, what I went with in the end is a `text-align:center` on the container, and then giving `float:left` to the `i` element inside the container. Not the most elegant but it works and I suppose this way I'll do the others as well.

Thank you for reaching out, appreciate it.

Comment: Will post here soon.  Not sure why a "best approach" question went toxic.  Maybe it should have been tagged 'algorithm'.  You were essentially looking for the optimal 'css html' algorithm to implement your specified styling and layout.